# getting at pointers in an array of struct passed as a void*

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a function with a signature like [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort):

```
const char* get_str(int i, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size);
```

I am passed arrays of pointers to `const char*`, or arrays of structs whose first field is a pointer to `const char*`.

What casts do I need to do to extract that pointer in the array element `i`?

I have tried casting the `base` as an array of char itself, so I can advance to the right element:

```
return *(const char**)(((const char*)base)[i * size]);
```

But the compiler is complaining: *warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]*

Comment: Uhm, could you add your exact call of `get_str()` as well as the declaration of whatever you pass to `base` to avoid misunderstanding? Also, it might help to state what's your goal doing that ... maybe there's something better than excessive casting.

Comment: something like this  return ( char * )( (char ** ) base )[ i * size ] ;

Comment: `return (const char *)(((char **)(base))[i * size]);`

Comment: If you have arrays of structs whose first field is a `const char *`, can't you just do `const char *str = *(const char **) (&array[i]);` without the void-pointer-and-size rigmarole? It seems to be much safer to do the size calculation with typed data.

Comment: @MOehm the size of the struct is not known to `get_str` function.  Its like qsort and bsearch etc; a C function that works on arrays of arbitrary structs.

Comment: The size is known, because you pass `sizeof(*something)` as `size` parameter. I just suggested to do the array offset calculation with the typed array. Your approach is to do the offset calculation with the raw byte data. There is a difference between your function and `qsort` and `bsearch`: You just need to access the array to one index.

Comment: "I am passed arrays of pointers to const char*, or arrays of structs whose first field is a pointer to const char*."  Those are different types, so what are you actually passing, a pointer to `const char*`? How does it make any sense to have an array in one case and a struct in another situation, then use the same function?

Comment: To emphasize Lundin's point: You need to choose between *array of `const char *`* and whatever `struct`; you can't have both.

Comment: @Seb how do you qsort or bsearch an arbitrary array of something?  Of course you can have both!  Like qsort and bsearch, you pass in a size and nmemb count.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to implement a type or identification sytem for structs like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct a {
    const char *id;
    int x;
};

struct b {
    const char *id;
    double d;
};

union any {
    struct a a;
    struct b b;
};

int main()
{
    struct a a[] = {{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}, {"three", 3}};
    struct b b[] = {{"pi", 3.1415}, {"e", 2.71}};
    union any any[3];

    any[0].a = a[0];
    any[1].b = b[0];
    any[2].a = a[1];

    puts(get_str(1, a, 3, sizeof(*a)));
    puts(get_str(1, b, 2, sizeof(*b)));
    puts(get_str(1, any, 3, sizeof(*any)));

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the following works:

```
const char* get_str(int i, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    const char *p = base;
    const char **pp = (const char**) (p + i * size);

    return *pp;
}
```

This can be written in one line as:

```
const char* get_str(int i, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    return *(const char**) ((const char *) base + i * size);
}
```

But I think that the detour via void pointers is not necessary. You can do the address calculations with the typed array:

```
puts(*(const char **) (&a[1]));
puts(*(const char **) (&b[1]));
puts(*(const char **) (&any[1]));
```

If you wrap that in a function:

```
const char *get_str(const void *str)
{
    return *(const char **) str;
}
```

you get:

```
puts(get_str(&a[1]));
puts(get_str(&b[1]));
puts(get_str(any + 1));
```

which is more readable than the `qsort`ish syntax in my opinion.

This works, because you acces only one element at a known position. The functions `bsort` and `qsort`, however, can't use this technique, because they have to access the array at several indices and hence must be able to do the index calculation themselves.

Comment: I'd suggest that the last sentence should be: _The function `bsearch` and `qsort`, however, do not use this technique because they are passed a comparison function which knows how to handle the data type being searched for or sorted._  Not so much _can't_ as _don't_, and they don't because they're passed a function attuned to the data structure being worked on.  (But +1 because you've given basically the answer that I would have given had you not done so first — thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

### Find me (well, "yet another" but suppose this parentheses never existed!) a bug in that compiler and I give you a *free* cookie!

The compiler is right. This

```
*(const char**)(((const char*)base)[i * size]);
```

Will type-compile to something like (syntax: `expresion -> type`)...

```
base -> const void*
(const char*)base -> (const char*)const void*
(((const char*)base)[i * size]) -> *(const char*)const void* -> const char // Here's the problem!
(const char**)(((const char*)base)[i * size]) -> (const char**)const char // Now, this is *not* good...
*(const char**)(((const char*)base)[i * size]) -> *(const char**)const char -> const char* // Well, we have now just perfectly dereferenced '~'...
```

Not very sane, isn't it?*

**BTW**: You don't give us enough information for me to provide a full solution to your problem. What are those `struct`s you talk about?

**Edit**: May this help you (written according to comments)?

```
*(const char**)&(((const unsigned char*)base)[size * i])
```

Comment: They are abritrary structs.  Its like qsort and bsearch; I want this function to work on any array of anything where the first field in the struct is a const char*.

Comment: Sadly, finding bugs in compilers is quite common... you must be baking a lot of cookies.

Comment: @Lundin: I use "cookies" in this kind of "assertions" as a self-protective comment. If the comment is actually false (but I *think* it isn't), well... cookies are cheap :).

Comment: My web browser tells me I shouldn't accept cookies from people I don't know anyhow.

Comment: @Will: Please elaborate a little bit. I'm not understanding what you say, and I can't edit/improve the answer without noticing I don't know what to write.

Comment: @Lundin: Time to buy Mozilla/Google/Microsoft/The Tor Project/MyBrowser Inc. with cookies then!